# Transpose with VBA in EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I have some data in excell like this:

```
1A
1B
1C
2A
2B
2C
3A
3B
3C
```

I want this:

```
1A 2A 3A
1B 2B 3B
1C 2C 3C
```

And this is my formula in VBA, but I have wrong data.

```
Public Sub TransposePaste()


'Value we want to step by
Dim stepVal As Long
stepVal = 3


'Declare start row variable (-1)
Dim row As Long
row = 0

'Declare the column the data is coming from
Dim col As Long
col = 1

'Declare and set worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1

'end row of the data
Dim endRow As Long


endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row

    'cycle to end of data end of data...
    For i = 1 To endRow Step stepVal

    'increment row each time
    row = row + 1

        'cycle through the columns outputting the data
        For j = 1 To stepVal

        Sheet1.Cells(row, j).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + j - 1, col).Value

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Any idea and help?

Comment: Also here's an extra tip. `ws` variable isn't needed. You've used the free `sheet1` variable well -- just use that everywhere. You'd only need to use `ws` here if there were a chance in future you might want to use a different sheet (rather than sheet1)

Comment: This post looks similar than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480022/excel-vba-transpose-variable-column-range-to-variable-rows/47480406?noredirect=1#comment81916286_47480406

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
Sheet1.Cells(row, j).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i + j - 1, col).Value
```

To this:

```
Sheet1.Cells(row, j + 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells((row - 1) * stepVal + j, col).Value
```

*Also use `Option Explicit` and declare those `i` and `j` variables!*

---

I would have done it slightly differently though. It's better to build up your array in memory and then dump it back out to the worksheet when it's complete. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim v As Variant, output As Variant
    Dim col As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    col = 3

    v = Sheet1.Range("A1:A9").Value 'input range
    ReDim output(1 To Int(UBound(v, 1) / col), 1 To col)

    For i = 1 To UBound(output)
        For j = 1 To col
            output(i, j) = v((i - 1) * col + j, 1)
        Next j
    Next i

    With Sheet1.Range("C1") 'output range
        .Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
    End With
End Sub
```